# Error in Selenium WebDriver basic java project

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, timeoutexception

I get the following error when run seleniumWebdriver project in Eclipse.

```
Started ChromeDriver
port=49011
version=26.0.1383.0
log=C:\Users\testuser\workspace\WebDriver_Project\chromedriver.log
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_17'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:107)
    at test.test.main(test.java:17)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d', time: '2013-02-27 20:53:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_17'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:527)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:49011/status] to be available after 20014 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
    ... 10 more
```

My code in Eclipse as follows. I added all the jar file which comes with the selenium java zip file

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\testuser\\Documents\\SW\\Testing\\selenium-2.31.0\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com.au/");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        element.sendKeys("mysql excel 2013");
        element.submit();
    }

}
```

Please help me out to find out where I got wrong.

Comment: looks like it just timed out.

Comment: If you are sure that ChromeDriver.exe path is right, check that chrome also is in the path.

Comment: what is at line 17 in your code??

Comment: have you started, selenium server standalone ?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the 64 bit version of the required driver?

Comment: Hi Percetion, In the following link there is no specific 64 bit chrome driver  https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Comment: Hi Oliver, line 17 is ` WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();'

Comment: Hi Buddy, Do we need selenium server standalone when run test locally with Webdriver

Comment: What version of Chrome?

Comment: Chrome browser Version 26.0.1410.64 m

Answer (score 0):

selenium seems to wait for some response on port 49011. May be some other app is blocking the port. Use netstat to check the open ports.

Comment: Hi Sajith, This is the netstat results

Comment: TCP    0.0.0.0:49011          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: netstat -aux to see which process using that port

Comment: Hi Sajith, Is netstat -aux work in windows8? Doesn't work for me

Comment: Othere issue is each time I run the test it gives different port no       `Started ChromeDriver
port=43105
version=26.0.1383.0`

Comment: I was wrong. I guessed another process may be blocking webdriver port so it cannot work as expected. But by the way you describe it it is not. Have you tried using firefox driver instead of chrome to see how that works out ?

Comment: For for windows, firefox came as `Nightly` (browser name) for `windows 8`. Is that OK. Other thing is for firefox do I need to have `selenium-server-stanalone.jar`. Because for chrome I downloaded ONLY `selenium-java-2.31.0.zip.` As per findings firefox driver included in `selenium-server-stanalone.jar`.

Comment: Hi f.cipriani, `netstat -ab` works, but cannot see the process name against port number

Comment: Is the .exe name that we get there?

Comment: How to set the System.setProperty parameter when path is set in Environmental Variable for ChromeDriver, `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",<???>);`

Comment: Following error shows when debug the application is that relevant to the isse?  `Class File Editor
Source not Found
The JAR File C:\Users\.....\selenium-java-2.31.0.jar has no source attachement`

Answer (score 0):

has anyone figured this out? My tests work just fine if you run it standalone without grails

Answer (score 0):

You are still using selenium -2.31.0 `\\selenium-2.31.0\\chromedriver.exe`. Please install newest version of selenium, `3.11.0` from [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Also please install latest version of chrome driver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) . If not latest anything higher then `version 2.35` should work.

Then run your test and let us know what you see.